# Bug with Tooltip and ListPointPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, bugs, tooltip

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and persisting through 11.2.0. Fixed in 11.3.**

---

The coordinates of a point in a three dimensional graph can be shown in a tooltip:

```
ListPointPlot3D[Tooltip[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {50, 3}]], PlotStyle -> {PointSize[.02]}]
```

This works fine in Mathematica 9, but in Mathematica 10 the tooltip now shows for all points the same list with a.o. the Point expression with the coordinates of all points. (Mathematica 10.0.1 on both Windows 7 and Windows 8). That seems at least undesirable behaviour to me.

This is a workaround:

```
ListPointPlot3D[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {50, 3}], PlotStyle -> {PointSize[.02]}] /. 
  Point[x_] :> {Tooltip[Point[#], #] &  /@ x}
```

Comment: This looks like a bug.  Also `Tooltip /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {50, 3}]` does not work when I believe it should, as it does in `ListPlot`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'd argue that the OPs behavior is correct as `Tooltip` wraps the entire data set. The behavior you mention is clearly a bug, and is known.

Comment: @rcollyer Pardon me, what is a bug and what is not a bug?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The OPs version `ListPointPlot3D[Tooltip[...]]` is not a bug as `Tooltip` surrounds the entire data set. The v9 behavior was incorrect. However, `ListPointPlot3D[Tooltip /@ {...}]` throwing all sorts of fun messages is a bug.

Comment: @rcollyer So you're saying the fact that `ListPlot[Tooltip[Range@12]]` functions nicely in 10.1.0 is also a bug?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'd say it is surprising as from the docs "Tooltip[expr] is equivalent to Tooltip[expr,expr]", and yet `Plot[Tooltip[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}], {x, 0, 10}]` is given as an example ... How about we chalk this up to sleep deprivation (newborn at home), and forget the whole thing?

Comment: @rcollyer Sleep deprivation sucks.  You have my sympathy.

Comment: @rcollyer. Of course you are right that the current result in version 10 is in line with the documentation. But the result is highly undesirable and I do not see any reason for changing the version 9 behaviour.

Comment: @FredSimons it depends on which part of the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html) you look at. Under the details section, `Tooltip[a]` becomes `Tooltip[a,a]`, but this [example](http://wolfram.com/xid/0enyh4v7w-dls6a6) explicitly contradicts this. So, it is now not clear to me which is correct. However, the details section is usually given weight over examples, so ... someone switched it back to that behavior. A good change? Debatable. Inline with some interpretation of the docs? Clearly. :P

Comment: v11.3 on macOS works as expected, i.e., each point has tooltip with the point's individual coordinates. If verified on other systems then this is corrected in v11.3

Comment: @Bob. Nice observation, thanks. On my windows installation it is corrected as well.

Comment: I don't know why this popped up, but on 13 it seems to be working correctly.